# How to locate FAST search server?

Tags: 2010, search, enterprise-search, infrastructure, fast

I am trying to identify which server (name and ip address) hosts the FAST search.
I can't seem to find server-specific information on either Central Administration (servers in farm, search, etc.) or using Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication.

Ping/nslookup hits the load balancer so no luck there.

I don't have access to a list with all servers I don't know where to look.

I am hoping that this is a trivial question and I am just not looking in the right place.

Thanks.

Comment: which SharePoint Version?2010? all servers in the same farm? do you have access to manager servers in farm and services on server?

Comment: SP2010. all servers in the same farm. can see servers and services. search server doesn't seem to be part of the farm servers.

Comment: from servers in farm, can you see any server running the search services? also from central admin > Secuirty > Manage Trust....see if you have trust here.....

Comment: manage trust has a few unrelated servers. search service is running on application servers but they don't seem to take me anywhere with the server name.

Comment: ok, one more thing, from central admin > Appplciation management >Manage service applications...can you access the search service application's admin page

Comment: yes, I have that

Comment: then go there and click on the topology...if possible the share the screens shots of Servers in Farm as well as Topology

Comment: the topology links show again, the names of the application servers running the search service, and the sql servers with the databases. no telling which is the server with fast installed

Comment: can you share the screen print with marked the server name...

Comment: if it is a must I can do that, but it is pretty much the regular admin page such as this one: http://mscerts.programming4.us/image/201106/Using%20Enterprise%20Search_1.jpg. if you have an instance and you tell me you can see the fast server name, than I would believe it, otherwise I don't think we will find it in CA

Comment: You sure it is fast search install over here. because what i am seeing the Sp2010 Search service application configured on the W8R2SP10. query, crawl and Admin all component configured on that server.

Comment: that is an example I found, because I want to avoid sharing the screen. fast is definitely installed, I simply don't know the server. I am starting to think that there is no way to know, at least from the UI

Comment: that's fine, But what server is listed infront of Query, crawl, index? If it is your app server then that's the server where you have the search.

Comment: I think you are confusing the server where the search service is running, and the server where we installed the FAST setup, which is an independent server, not directly linked to the sharepoint farm.

Comment: What i am sure, if Fast search is installed on seprate server/farm then you cannt see all these from sharepoint central admin. another way you can check from add /remove programm from control panel on all servers and see if you can see fastsearch server install their. also check this....https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff381272(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23083/discussion-between-waqas-sarwar-mcse-and-tiago-duarte).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way I found to really know which server has FAST installed.
(without opening each server one-by-one and checking for the FAST 2010 Server in installed programs)

1. Browse one of the application servers
2. Look for `Install_Info.txt` (default FAST configuration output file)
3. Pray that someone copied it to one of the servers (and the server hasn't changed since)

There it is!

> Query Service Location HTTP (default):            http://FAST:11111

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with PowerShell `Get-SPServiceInstance`?

```
Get-SPServiceInstance
```

or

```
Get-SPServiceInstance -Server ServerA
```

Reference: [Get-SPServiceInstance](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607570(v=office.14).aspx)

Comment: I can get the "Server" property, but it contains the SharePoint server, not the search server/machine FQDN, where FAST is installed.
(Get-SPServiceInstance | where-object {$_.TypeName -match "
search"})[1] | select Server